# Function that creates a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function, user_dialogue() that asks for the name of two files. This function needs to handle Errors such as IOError. The two files should then run through another function I created, that is called encryption_function.

The program should work like this:

Name of new encrypted file: out_file.txt

Name of file to be encrypted:blah.txt

That resulted in an error! Please try again.

Name of file to be encrypted: my file.csv

Encryption completed!

This is my code so far:

```
def user_dialogue():
    file1 = open(input("New name of file: "), 'w')

    done = False

    while not done:
        try:
            file2 = open(input("Name of file that you want to encrypt: "), 'r')
        except IOError as error:
        print("File doesn't exist! The error is of the type: ", error)
        else:

        file2.close()

        done = True

    encrypt_file(file2,file1)
```

user_dialogue()

And this is my function encrypt_file:

```
def encrypt_file(in_file, out_file):
    fr = open(in_file, 'r')
    fileread = fr.read()
    encryptedfile = text_encryption_function.encrypt(fileread)
    fr.close()

    fw = open(out_file, 'a+')
    fw.write(encryptedfile)
    fw.close()

    return in_file, out_file
```

For some reason the code doesn't work! Any help please?

Comment: `encrypt_file()` expects 2 strings but you are passing files (only one of which you closed). Either pass the names, or change `encrypt_file()` to accept files.

Comment: And please add indentation where needed.

Comment: In python3 you should use context manager `with`:
`with open(input("New name of file: "), 'w') as file1:`

Comment: Thanks for your answers!  How do I change (encrypt_file) so that it can accept files as input?

Answer (score 0):

Using context manager `with`:

```
def user_dialogue():
    try:
        with open(input("Name of file that you want to encrypt: "), 'r') as file2:
            try:
                with open(input("New name of file(encrypted): "), 'w') as file1:
                    encrypt_file(file2, file1)
            except IOError as e3:
                print('No access')

    except FileNotFoundError as e1:
        print('No such file')
    except IOError as e2:
        print('No access')



def encrypt_file(in_file, out_file):
    fileread = in_file.read()
    encryptedfile = text_encryption_function.encrypt(fileread)

    out_file.write(encryptedfile)
```

Using try/except:

```
def user_dialogue():
    try:
        file2 = open(input("Name of file that you want to encrypt: "), 'r')
        try:
            file1 = open(input("New name of file(encrypted): "), 'w')
            encrypt_file(file2, file1)
        except IOError as e3:
            print('No access')
        else:
            file1.close()

    except FileNotFoundError as e1:
        print('No such file')
    except IOError as e2:
        print('No access')
    else:
        file2.close()



def encrypt_file(in_file, out_file):
    fileread = in_file.read()
    encryptedfile = text_encryption_function.encrypt(fileread)

    out_file.write(encryptedfile)
```

Comment: Where exactly in the code should I add try/ except? Should it be right after
"with open..."?

Comment: `open` can raise `IOError` so wrap `with ...:`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. :( I'm very new to programming. 

Thanks for help but if anyone could explain more it would be appreciated!